# Does a creature have cover when moving through an ally's space?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, opportunity-attack, cover

Suppose that creatures A, B, and C are positioned in a straight line, with A at the start, then an empty space, then B in the next space, and C in the space after that.

A has a reach weapon (and is an enemy of both B and C, not sure if that changes anything). C has soft cover from A, but is also out of reach. Now, C moves closer to A - through B's square, then into the empty square. Movement into the empty square would normally provoke an attack of opportunity for moving out of the square threatened via reach, but *if* B provides soft cover for those moving *through* his space, that attack cannot be taken.

Do any rules, FAQs, etc. rule either way on whether a creature has cover when moving through an ally's space?

Comment: That’s a damn good question; I don’t think there’s an answer for it. Here’s hoping someone knows something I don’t!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On [Cover](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Cover) says, "When making a melee attack against a target that isn’t adjacent to you (such as with a reach weapon), use the rules for determining cover from ranged attacks." That's done by doing this:

> To determine whether your target has cover from your ranged attack, choose a corner of your square. If any line from this corner to any corner of the target’s square passes through a square or border that blocks line of effect or provides cover, or through a square occupied by a creature, the target has cover (+4 to AC).

Also, on Cover and Attacks of Opportunity says, "You can’t execute an attack of opportunity against an opponent with cover relative to you."

However, [Moving through a Square](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Moving-Through-a-Square) says, "You can move through a square occupied by a friendly character, unless you are charging. When you move through a square occupied by a friendly character, that character *doesn’t* provide you with cover" (emphasis mine).

Thus, in the scenario described in the question, when C takes a move action to move *into* his ally B's square, A *can't* make an attack of opportunity against C because the attack of opportunity would've been provoked from the square C just left, and C has soft cover from A in that square. However, when C exits B's square (as he typically must), if C exits into a space that that A still threatens, C will provoke attacks of opportunity normally as C being in the square with B doesn't provide either of them with cover.